# Get latest state from angular-redux store

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, angular5, angular-redux

I create own store

```
export interface IAppState {
    cartData:ICartItem[];

    lastUpdate:Date;
}
```

and add some reducer to handle ADD and REMOVE actions

But in many places I just need latest data from store. According to documentation it is enough to add attr `@select()` to store item add you will get current state.

But I've created some service which will do all work like get, add and remove items from store

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
    @select() private cartData: ICartItem[] ;
    constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) { }

    getItems() {
        return this.cartData;
    }

    addItem(item: IItem) {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: ADD_CART_ITEM, cartItem : item});
    }

    removeItem(itemId: string) {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: REMOVE_CART_ITEM, id: itemId});
    }

    removeAllItems() {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: REMOVE_ALL_CART_ITEMS});
    }
}
```

But problem - when I init `myCartData` property with `getItems` on init of my component, later I can add or remove some item, but `myCartData` property will not be updated after all this.

So how can I get latest state from store using such service? Or this approach is bad and I need to get state from store directly when I want without any custom services?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CartService {
    @select('cartData')  cartData$: Observable<ICartItem[]> ;

    constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) { }

    addItem(item: IItem) {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: ADD_CART_ITEM, cartItem : item});
    }

    removeItem(itemId: string) {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: REMOVE_CART_ITEM, id: itemId});
    }

    removeAllItems() {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch({type: REMOVE_ALL_CART_ITEMS});
    }
}
```

In your component file just subscribe to `cardService.cardData$`, or use an async pipe in your template.